# $\{X_n\}$ are i.i.d and nonnegative r.v.s such that $\mathbb{E}X_1=+\infty$, prove that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \to +\infty$, a.s.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

I have $\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=+\infty)=0 \ \mbox{or} \ 1$, according to the Kolmogorov 0-1 law.

I want to use the method of contradiction: Suppose $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ does not converge to $+\infty$, a.s., i.e. $\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=+\infty)=0$. In other words, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i<+\infty$, a.s. And, I want to get contradiction by
\begin{equation}
\infty>\mathbb{E}(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)=\mathbb{E}X_1=+\infty
\end{equation}
But there are two problems,

1. $X<\infty$, a.s. can't guarantee that $\mathbb{E}X<\infty$
2. I can’t use the DCT nor the MCT to exchange the order of limits.

I wonder know if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i<+\infty$, a.s. is equivalent to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\to $ constant, a.s.？Because $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is measurable with respect to tail event, maybe a constant. Please tell me if this is right? If yes, two problems above are solved.

Comment: This has been  answered earlier. Aplly SLLN to $\min \{X_i,M\}$ and the vary $M$.

Comment: @geetha290krm: I can get $\lim_{M\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(X_i\wedge M)=\mathbb{E}(X_i)=\infty$, but how to switch the order of limits  $\lim_{M\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i\wedge M)$?

Comment: $X_i \geq \min \{X_i,M\}$ always.

Comment: If $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \nrightarrow +\infty$ then there may not be a limit.